# How to map an array into a List of Vector2s in Flutter for FlutterFlame?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flame

I need to convert an array from Firebase into a List of Vector2s in Flutter for FlutterFlame.

Comment: What is the current format in the array?

Comment: just an array filled with numbers. Ex: [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,43,2,]

Comment: So should that list just be converted to [Vector2(1,2), Vector2(3, 4) ...]? Or what's the x and y values here?

Comment: the x values are the even numbers and the y values are the odd number

Comment: sorry, not "numbers'. but "elements

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather from the comments you have an array of integers like this:

```dart
final numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 43];
```

You can convert this to a list of `Vector2` in many ways, this is one way to do it:

```dart
final vectors = [
  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i+=2)
    Vector2(numbers[i].toDouble(), numbers[i+1].toDouble())
];
```